# In an Objective-C block, can you make the outer method return? a la Ruby proc?

Tags: objective-c, ruby, closures

In Ruby, calling `return` inside a block or even nested blocks will transfer control and return from the innermost wrapping method, I'm talking proc. In a Ruby lambda `return` returns from the block itself and the calling method continues, and this is also how Objective-C blocks work.

Is there a way to get Ruby's proc semantics w.r.t returning in Objective-C? I want a return inside a block to return the outer method.

Comment: and if the block is run outside of the scope of the method it's defined in, what would return do then?

Comment: @ newacct: return from the scope where it's being run, like Ruby... worst case `main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Ruby, but the only way for an ObjC Block to exert control over its enclosing method is for that method to test its return value.

This could be as simple as:

```
- (id)bloviate:(id (^)(void))bombast 
{
    // The method returns the results of the Block call;
    // thus, strictly speaking, the method returns when
    // the Block does.
    return bombast();
}
```

Or you can check the return value and conditionally return from the method:

```
- (id)elucidate:(BOOL (^)(id))explanation
{
    id obj = /* Get some object */;
    if( explanation(obj) ) {
        return obj;
    }
    // Else continue
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is NO, a return statement within a block will only return from the block. As shown below, you could certainly build something not to inelegant using a combination of exceptions, `@try` statements and a macros but in the end I think this would be more confusing than anything else.

```
@interface MPReturnFromNestedBlockException : NSException
+ (void) returnExceptionWithResult:(id)result;
@end;

@implementation MPReturnFromNestedBlockException
+ (void) returnExceptionWithResult:(id)result
{
    MPReturnFromNestedBlockException *exception = (id)
        [self exceptionWithName:@"MPReturnFromMethodException"
                         reason:nil
                       userInfo:@{@"result":result}];
    [exception raise];
}
@end

#define abruptReturn(value)\
    ({ [MPReturnFromNestedBlockException returnExceptionWithResult:value]; })

#define blockMayReturnAbruptly(block)\
({\
    id result = nil;\
    @try { block(); }\
    @catch(MPReturnFromNestedBlockException *exception) {\
        result = exception.userInfo[@"result"];\
    }\
    result;\
})


int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSArray *numbers = @[@1, @2, @3];

        id value = blockMayReturnAbruptly(^{
            [numbers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id numA, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
                double a = [numA doubleValue];
                [numbers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id numB, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
                    double b = [numB doubleValue];
                    NSLog(@"%f x %f = %f", a, b, a*b);
                    if (a * b > 3)
                        abruptReturn(@(a*b));
                }];
            }];
        });

        NSLog(@"Result = %@", value);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is the following:

```
1.000000 x 1.000000 = 1.000000
1.000000 x 2.000000 = 2.000000
1.000000 x 3.000000 = 3.000000
2.000000 x 1.000000 = 2.000000
2.000000 x 2.000000 = 4.000000
Result = 4
```

Comment: This is a great idea, but exceptions are not intended to be used for control flow in ObjC. [Cocoa is not exception-safe.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Exceptions/Articles/ExceptionsAndCocoaFrameworks.html)

Comment: You could also add that it might not work nicely with multi-threaded code for which blocks are often used.

Comment: I've checked and it definitly does not work when the return macro is used from another thread. It makes sense because the exception traping machinery has not been installed on the call-stack of the running thread.